# What is this patent US20150162784 all about? and how is it relevant in other countries?

Tags: us20150162784

In reference to the patent: [US20150162784](https://www.google.com/patents/US20150162784)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document you linked to is a patent application. The issued patent corresponding to that application is [US9566867B2](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9566867B2/en). Essentially, what this patent seems to be about is using plugged in electric car batteries to provide power energy storage to the electric grid. It is a US patent only so it only imparts protection in the US. I looked on [Espacenet](https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/inpadocPatentFamily?CC=US&NR=9566867B2&KC=B2&FT=D&ND=&date=20170214&DB=&locale=) and didn't find any equivalent patents in other countries. It would, however represent prior art in other countries.

Comment: could you give more detailed description about the patent  US9566867B2

Comment: @NidhinSathish do you have a particular question or do you just not want to invest the time of reading it?

Comment: @NidhinSathish Technical questions are actually off topic for this site. However, if you read the patent and have specific questions (especially about what the claims mean) feel free to ask either by editing your question or posting a new one. If this answer is acceptable, please consider accepting it by clicking the check mark.